# adding Outlook 2013 mailitem contextmenu. VS 2012 C#

Tags: visual-studio-2012, outlook-addin

Hi i want to add a new button to outlook 2013 mailitem contextmenu. 
I use VS 2012 C#.

I seached internet but cant find a way to do this, im upgrading an Outlook 2010 addin which modified the contextmenu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In visual studio on project select add new item. Choose Ribbon(XML).

add following to XML file:

```
<contextMenus>
    <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuMailItem">
     <menu id="ArcIT" label="ArcIT">
       <button id="MyContextMenuMailItem"
           label="ContextMenuMailItem"
           onAction="OnMyButtonClick"/>
     </menu >
   </contextMenu>
  </contextMenus>
```

in ribbon.cs class add following method

```
public void OnMyButtonClick(Office.IRibbonControl control)
    {


        if (control.Context is Outlook.Selection)
        {
            Outlook.Selection sel = control.Context as Outlook.Selection;
            Outlook.MailItem mail = sel[1];
            MessageBox.Show(mail.Subject.ToString());

        }
    }
```

method has to be public. This method shows a box with subject from the mail u right clicked.

Comment: Add the XML where? When you add a new item `Ribbon(XML)` it comes with it's own xml already.

Comment: @TheMuffinMan Replace that xml with the one given above.